How to send command to printer using python for printing PDF file on windows?
I need to run a Python script that directly sends commands to the printer for printing the PDF file /test.pdf.
I don't want to use any proprietary or third-party tools.
I can use the win32print library to send raw commands to the printer.
Need help with printing the PDF files on Windows.
On Linux, I have tested, the below code prints the PDF.
printer_name = 'HP laserjet 001'
command = ["lp", "-d", printer_name, "-n", "1", '/test.pdf']
subprocess.run(command)

Is there any way to do it on Windows?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626918/pythons-win32api-only-printing-to-default-printer
